# Nameless environments spacing side-effects

Tags: spacing, environments

I was under the assumption that wrapping a section of text within curly brackets effectively creates an implicit environment where I can temporarily change some settings, for instance the font size:

```
Some text in normal size
{
    \footnotesize
    Some text in footnote size
}
back to normal size
```

This does works but I have now run into cases where using `{}` has side effects on spacings. For instance when I have multiple paragraphs the last paragraph is spaced further vertically than the other paragraphs. Is this expected? What's the best way to temporarily change settings without any other side effects?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by "spaced further vertically".  Would you be able to provide a MWE that shows what you're talking about?

Comment: The text you present here is one single paragraph and the line spacing is determined at the end of the paragraph thus the line spacing specified by `\footnotesize` is never used. As already mentioned please explain in more detail what exactly your goal is here.

Comment: You have to add a `\par` before the closing brace.

Comment: \par did the trick!

Comment: Technically, braces form a group.  One can also use `\bgroup ... \egroup` or `\begingroup ... \endgroup`.  Note that ending a line with a brace adds a space, so use `{%` and `}%`.

Comment: you would get essentially the same from an environment but yes code yoy show is adding a lot of space

Comment: You also need a `%` after `{`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line spacing in a paragraph is set by the value of `\baselineskip` at the end of the paragraph so you should always make sure the end of the paragraph is in the scope of a size change. However empty  brace groups (or environments) will affect the space in lots of ways, you need to be aware of and avoid adding white space, typically by adding `%` at ends of lines.

Consider a version of your example, but without the size change, spacing is already affected:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

aaa bbb

aaa
{
}
bbb

\end{document}
```

The `{}` markup has forced three word spaces rather than one between aaa and bbb.

The markup should be

```
aaa
{%
}%
bbb
```

Comment: Get out from my property!

Comment: @egreg squatters rights